# Submitting JSP form data to servlet

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, tree, jqtree

I currently have this tree node which was created from  http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/. I am trying to implement this tree, so that when a user clicks on a node in the tree, it will send the data to my servlet. Is there any way to do this?  I am currently using JSP. My initial solution was to add a button so that the button (with form tag) will do post action when it is being clicked(after selecting my node), but i would like to know if there is any solution without using a button. I also thought of using ajax but im new to this and am not sure if it works. Really need some help. Thanks
  My Tree:

```
$('#tree1').tree({data: data});
    $('#tree1').bind(
             'tree.click',
            function(event) {
                if (event.node) {
                    // node was selected
                        node = event.node.name;
                    alert(node);
                    // send node value to servlet
                }
                else {
                }});
```

HTML

```
<div id="tree1"></div>
```

My Initial idea

```
  $('#saveCat').click(function(){
        document.getElementById('mainCat').value = node;
        document.getElementById('action').value = "savecategory";
     });


  <form action="TopicCloudServlet">
    <button id="saveCat" class=" catbtn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="mainCat" name="mainCat" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found 1 solution which is very simple( why didn't i thought of it)

1. Add an id to the form that is going to be submitted.
2. At the javascript where u want your form to be submitted,

   document.forms["FormID"].submit();

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are dynamically creating the tree , you can add extra elements as attributes to each nodes of the tree when you render it.Do not worry,your custom attributes will be ignored by the browser.

Below "nodevalue" is your own attribute that you add to the div dynamically when rendering the tree to uniquely identify each node.

```
<div id="tree1">
   <div nodevalue="node1" class="mynode">
   </div>
  <div nodevalue="node2" class="mynode">
   </div>
</div>
```

Then write a jquery class selector onclick event and get the unique ID of the clicked node.

```
$(".mynode").on("click",function(){

    alert(this.attr("nodevalue"));

});
```

`this.attr("nodevalue")`

will give the value of the node you currently clicked.

Comment: hi @Tito Cheriachan, sry but maybe i wasnt clear enough. I am able to get the value of the node when i click on it; at the line where  alert(node);. What i would like to do is to do a form method after this line to post a form to my servlet

Comment: You can use ajax POST to submit the value to the servlet.This will get you started http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong but the example u gave makes use of a button  to submit a form. What if i would like it to do without the button, like when i click on a node and use the ajax POST. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible , you don't need a button to submit the form. When you click on the node , you can directly call an ajax with "type" POST and pass the values to the servlet in "data" part of the ajax request.